# Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to append the node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in appending a content to a particular node .
Here is my Jsfidde http://jsfiddle.net/usezpkj2/7/

I have a main list

> Project1
>
> Project2

Inside the Project1 and project2 there are some list items inside a `<ul class=hiddendivcontent` which is hidden and when clicking on the `glyhicon-chevron-down` , the list will be shown. Here is the code for that:

```
$(".glyphicon ").click( function ( e ){ 
   e.preventDefault() // prevent default action - hash doesn't appear in url
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(target.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-right")){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
    
    $(this).closest("li").append($('.hiddendivcontent'));
        $(this).parent().children(".hiddendivcontent").toggle();
    }
    else if(target.hasClass("glyphicon-chevron-down")){
         $(e.target).toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-down');
         $(this).parent().children(".hiddendivcontent").toggle();
        
    }
    
} );
```

When i click on the list items *Menu1*, it should again append the `<ul class="hiddendivcontent">..</ul>` as a child inside the *Menu1*. So finally my output should be like

```
Project1
   Menu1
     Menu1
     Menu2
   Menu2
Project2
```

The problem is , when i click on the Menu1, I am getting an exception:

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.
```

The problem is with the append(). But I dont know how to solve it.I am new to Jquery and Javascript. Can anyone please suggest me some ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error says it is. You're trying to append:

```
<ul class="hiddendivcontent">
    <li class="listvalue">Menu1</li>
    <li class="listvalue">Menu2</li>
</ul>
```

Inside of itself. If you want to add another block of html that looks the same you would do something like this:

```
$(this).closest("li").append($('<ul class="NewList"> <li class="listvalue">Menu3</li></ul>'));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25q40a87/

Comment: I need to add the same class not  a new one.

Comment: Then change the class to whatever you want. I used NewList as an example, it can be anything.

Comment: I want to add the same class. In JSFiddle I have given just a overview of my project. Sorry I should have mentioned in my question, the value in hiddendivcontent changes whenever i click on the particular item(Menu1). But it shouls follow the same structure as hiddendivcontent

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do. Should clicking Menu1 toggle the visibility of menu3? I changed the code to append the list with the class here http://jsfiddle.net/25q40a87/1/

Comment: Yes. Thanks for ur Jsfiddle code. In your code Third level are always repeated in each levels. In my case thirdlevel values changes based on the secondlevel dynamically. Jus imagine a kind of tree hierarchichal structure. It should be like a child under a child.

Comment: In your case, the tree is already predefined and it is easy to show and hide the li using toggle. In my case, the li inside hiddendivcontent gets the value from the server and it displays

Comment: I think I understand what you're aiming for now. How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/qap3s3r6/1/
All of the third level content is set during runtime.